# How to plot 2 planes in GNU Octave

Tags: math, plot, octave, plane

I want to draw two planes in same figure, how can I do this?

```
x + y + z = 1
2x - y + 3z = 4
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ranges of `x` and `y` in which to display planes:

```
X = linspace(-100,100,10);
Y = linspace(-100,100,10);
[ XX, YY ] = meshgrid(X,Y);
```

Calculating `z` coordinate for planes:

```
ZZ1 = 1 - XX - YY;
ZZ2 = 4/3 - 2/3 * XX + 1/3 *YY;
```

Displaying:

```
figure;
hold on;
mesh(XX,YY,ZZ1);
mesh(XX,YY,ZZ2);
```

[image]

Comment: Hi do you sure if this still works? I tried this in Octave on Windows. My Octave version is 3.6.4. Its not working. I recorded a video of what is happening with me and have uploaded it to the youtube [here](https://youtu.be/ucPzpl5fDYA). Can you please have a look. I tried it on Android Octave too, but getting exactly same behavior.

Comment: @Mahesha999 - You just need to rotate your graph to see it properly. Once viewing your graph, type 'r' and then use your mouse to rotate.